# how can i control the way columns layout in wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress

hi everyone how can i control the way my columns layout in WordPress posts i have a featured image in WordPress that's acting like its taking up the entire width of the first column but its only 150x150 is there a way to combine it with the second column? it can be seen here http://test.smartphonesource.org/category/articles/ my post excerpt is appearing below the image and i would like it to wrap around it and run down the page similar to this website here http://healthcave.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Add this css

.postingan2 > a {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

and you get result like attach image

[image]

Comment: thanks alot ankit thats exactly what i needed to do i really appreciate the help i was stuck on this for quite some time lol you provided a perfect resolution thanks =)